# Encrypt folders with Plasma Vault?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, encryption

I recently read an article on [OMG! UBUNTU!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/plasma-vault-create-encrypted-folder-linux) that said it was easy to encrypt folders using Plasma Vault. Unfortunately there was is no example given and I found it quite hard to find anything really about Plasma Vault or encryption of single folders. Is Plasma Vault still in development? Is it not yet available in KDE (2017-06-17)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plasma Vault lives on the system tray area and if you have it installed in your system,you can have its icon show up on the tray by enabling it through system tray settings->general->extra items->vaults. Once the icon is visible,click it and the generated GUI should be self explanatory.

If it is not installed on your system,you can get it[1] and manually build and install it but check first if it is not in repositories.

There is an alternative called SiriKali[2]. It is Qt based and is desktop independent and very easy to use.

A good start at knowing different folder based encryption tools and their differences is here[3].

[1] https://github.com/KDE/plasma-vault

[2] https://mhogomchungu.github.io/sirikali/

[3] https://nuetzlich.net/gocryptfs/comparison/

ps: SiriKali is one of my projects.

Comment: If sirikali is your own tool, please make that clear in your answer so that people don't consider it spam.